# Handling 'a' tag with a hover effect on moble devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't imagine anyone will be able to crack this but any help or a point in a right direction will be great.

I have a standard menu that has x number of links and those links on hover will open a sub menu. the Main links on click however are accessable pages.

```
<ul id="mainNavigation">
    <li>
        <a href="/somewhere.html">Main 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/somewhere2.html">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/somewhere3.html">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/somewhere4.html">Main 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/somewhere5.html">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/somewhere6.html">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On a landscape tablet the desktop menu shows but obviously the hover effect will not work. The real problem here is that I want the Main links to have a click to open the submenu and a second click on the Main to go to the href it has attached to it (Only on devices).

Basically the desktop:
Main links on hover open submenu
Main links on click will open a page

Tablets
Main links open submenu on first click
Main links will open a page on second click

I'm guessing maybe some media queries to target the ipad and make a custom menu, or maybe someone can suggest a jquery alternative.

Thanks

Comment: With this library you can put some conditional element inside your HTML and it seems a solution for your problem, https://github.com/Podders/Jquery-Media-Comments/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something for you doing what you ask...
But to hide an opened sub-menu... I'm not sure.

lol! How would you like it to return to hidden state?
I tought of a setTimeout for the moment.

This is the code so far:
[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/Lyqyrw?editors=1111)

**NOTE** To try on mobile and make it not execute on desktop, remove the `!` where it is said to reverse the logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Easy way to determine if the script executes on mobile.
  var isMobile=false;
  $(document).on("touchstart",function(){
    isMobile=true;
  });

  // Main links handler
  $(".mainLink").on("click",function(e){
    if(!isMobile){                            // REVERSE THIS LOGIC TO TRY ON MOBILE
      e.preventDefault();

      if( $(this).siblings("ul").find("li").is(":visible") ){
        console.log("sub is visible, open link!");

        window.location.assign( $(this).attr("href") );
      }else{
        console.log("sub is NOT visible, show sub-menu.");
        $(this).siblings("ul").show();
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".submenu").hide();
        },1500);  // 1,5 seconds to hide the sub-menu.
      }
    }
  });
  
  // Main links handler - Just to stop event propagation.
  $(".subLink").on("click",function(e){
    if(!isMobile){                            // REVERSE THIS LOGIC TO TRY ON MOBILE
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      console.log("SUB clicked, open link!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#mainNavigation li ul{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mainNavigation">
    <li>
        <a href="/somewhere.html" class="mainLink">Main 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/somewhere2.html" class="subLink">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/somewhere3.html" class="subLink">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/somewhere4.html" class="mainLink">Main 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/somewhere5.html" class="subLink">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/somewhere6.html" class="subLink">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```